# using guice with javafx and hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx-8, guice

I've got a `javafx` controller that looks like this

```
public class DictionaryFxController implements Initializable {

    @Inject
    private QueryTemplate queryTemplate;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        ....
        queryTemplate.insert(langs);
        ....
    }
}
```

My `application` class looks like this

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new ApplicationModule());
        Scene scene = null;
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        try {
            Parent root = loader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/dictionary.fxml"));
            loader.setControllerFactory(injector::getInstance);
            scene = new Scene(root);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }

        primaryStage.setTitle("Dictionary");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

My class that provides `Hibernate` session looks like this

```
@Singleton
public class HibernateController {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public HibernateController() {
        sessionFactory = new Configuration()
                .configure()
                .buildSessionFactory();
    }

    public Session openSession() {
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    private void close() {
        sessionFactory.close();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(sessionFactory.getSessionFactoryOptions().getServiceRegistry());
    }
}
```

I wire this class into `template` that I use to peform queries

```
public class QueryTemplate {
    private HibernateController hibernateController;

    @Inject
    public QueryTemplate(HibernateController controller) {
        this.hibernateController = controller;
    }

    public <T> void insert(List<T> objects) {
        try (Session session = hibernateController.openSession()) {
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

            // generalize
            objects.forEach(session::save);

            tx.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

I bound this class in the module

```
public class ApplicationModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(QueryTemplate.class);
    }
}
```

But when I start the application, it fails on the line

```
   queryTemplate.insert(langs);
```

because `queryTemplate` is null. 
What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the controller factory *after* loading the FXML; the controller will already have been created at that point. Since the `FXMLLoader` will use the default mechanism for creating the controller - i.e. simply calling the controller's default constructor - the controller is not managed by Guice and won't have its injected fields initialized.

You can fix the problem simply by reversing the order of the lines with `loader.setControllerFactory(...)` and `loader.load(...)`.

As an aside, it is better to set the location of an `FXMLLoader` than to use the `load(InputStream)` method. If you use the method taking a `Stream`, the location is not set, and location resolution will not work properly in your FXML file.

So replace

```
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    try {
        Parent root = loader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/dictionary.fxml"));
        loader.setControllerFactory(injector::getInstance);
        scene = new Scene(root);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
```

with

```
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/dictionary.fxml"));
    loader.setControllerFactory(injector::getInstance);
    try {
        Parent root = loader.load();
        scene = new Scene(root);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
```

You can combine the first two lines into the single line

```
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/dictionary.fxml"));
```

if you prefer.